# Meteor - cursor with limit set isn't reactive

Tags: meteor

I don't know if this is bug, but when i specify `limit`, the cursor on the client isn't reactive if some data that match the query already exists in the client collection.

For instance if have limit: 4 and there is already 1 record that match, than
it returns that one record and when next 3 records, which machtes the query, arrives from the server, the cursor isn't reactive (i am expecting
it will be evaluated again and it will return all those 4 records).

I found it because when i uncomment the line where i am fetching all records, my app works (because that cursor will reflect that new data are available). You can see that query is same, only except that `limit`.

```
messages = Messages.find(selector, {sort: {created: -1}, limit: MessagesAPI.LIMIT}).fetch();
 //Messages.find(selector, {sort: {created: -1}}).fetch()); 
 // if i uncomment the previous line, it works
```

**More code**

```
getMeteorState: function () {
        console.log("zde");
        var time = this.getParams().time;
        var dir = this.getParams().dir;
        //TODO: maybe check time and dir validity or let it crash ?
        var ready = Session.get("messages-ready");
        var params = {sort: MessagesAPI.sort.NEW, dir: dir == "prev" ? MessagesAPI.dir.PREV : MessagesAPI.dir.NEXT};
        if (time) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(time);
            params.date = d;
        }
        Meteor.subscribe("messages", params, function () {
            console.log("ready");
            Session.set("messages-ready", true);
        });

        var messages = [];
        if (ready) {
            var selector = {};
            if (time && dir) {
                selector.created = {};
                var cond = (dir == "prev" ? "$lt" : "$gt");
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(time);
                selector.created[cond] = date;
            }
            messages = Messages.find(selector, {sort: {created: -1}, limit: MessagesAPI.LIMIT}).fetch();
            //console.log(selector);
             // when i uncomment this, it will work
            //console.log(Messages.find(selector, {sort: {created: -1}}).fetch());
        }
        return {
            messages: messages
        };
    },
```

Comment: what happens if you take the .fetch() off?

Comment: @KeithNicholas: in messages will be just some LocalCollection instance

Comment: how are you using it?

Comment: @KeithNicholas: i am using React for my UI, so it will be probably hard to decode, but i will update the question

Comment: When you call .fetch,  the array you get isn't reactive

Comment: @KeithNicholas: no the array not, but that method will be reevaluated

Answer (score 1):

It is reactive.

If I create a default app and mod it like so

```
Messages = new Mongo.Collection("messages");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault("counter", 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get("counter");
    },
    messages: function() {
      var messages = Messages.find({},{sort: {text: -1},  limit: 4}).fetch();
      return messages;
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {      
      Session.set("counter", Session.get("counter") + 1);
      Messages.insert({text: Session.get("counter")});
    }
  });
}
```

and html

```
<head>
  <title>reactive</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}

</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>

  <div>
  {{#each messages}}
    {{text}}
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

No problem.  Manual insert via Mongo console reactively updates